# How to get and display API like the facebook graph in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4

I've went through most of the beginner rails books and I want to try creating something on my own. For a start, I just want to create a few pages in rails that will get from Facebook's api and display something like username, likes, post. I've searched around and couldn't find an answer. My friend recommended that I use a gem called fb_graph, but reviewing the documentation, I have no clue how to use it.

Thanks stackoverflow!

Comment: friendly advise: try to show what you have tried (even if it seems little) it will encourage ppl to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Graph API directly. The responses will be in JSON which you can then parse into Ruby hash. See the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/) for more details on to call specific and sample JSON responses. So here is general guide how to you can start playing around with this:-

1. Make a API Call to [Facebook using Graph API
   Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/). Keep playing around with api until you get a response you want. Note the request params you passed to get that response & JSON you received from facebook.
2. Send a HTTP request containing those same params in rails using [`koala`](https://github.com/arsduo/koala), ['fb_graph'](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) or just plain `NET:HTTP`. It doesn't matter what client you use to sent the request, as long as you send same params as in step1, you will get that familar JSON as response.
3. Now, once you have the json, just have to parse it. Provided, if the client library is not already doing that as most fb gems will turn JSON into ruby objects/hashes. But if they don't, then you have to do it manually, its something like `JSON.parse('JSON_RESPONSE_AS_STRING_GOES_HERE')`. after this you will have a plain-old ruby hash which is you can save to db, display in view or whatever you want to do.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I really appreciate it! I'm going to start working on that now! But to sum it up real quick, basically after I send in the data to the gem, the gem should parse it and then I need to save it to the db. Then from the views, I can call the information from the db using the models correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the general guideline. incase you get stuck with something like an error. Ask another question & remember to include the full error message & what you are trying to do.